# Using existing tables and its relations in rails 3.2 application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an existing application with lot of data and about 20 tables, how can I use them directly.
My database.yml file points to the MysQL database. Something like magic model generator.

Answer (score 1):

you can do the following

```
connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection()
results = connection.execute("#{your_sql_query_here}")
results.each do |row|
  puts row[0]
end
```

However I'd recommend you to associate them in a more coherent fashion.

Answer (score 0):

You would create a model for each one of them which is not much when you only have about 20.
In the model you would associate the table to them using the

```
set_table_name :name_of_your_table
```

Keep in mind the model name just have to be relavent enough to the table, because of the explicit set_table_name method they do not have to follow strict convention.

And to set relationships you would use the class_name just like this

```
has_many :fruits, :class_name => "CrazyFruit"
```

It might sound tedious but its the right way